# How to Sort List in Ascending Order by Firebase Childs (Numeric)?

Tags: android, list, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                list = new ArrayList<>();
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    Model userdetails = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Model.class);
                    Model listdata = new Model();

                    String name = userdetails.getName();
                    String points = userdetails.getPoints();

                    listdata.setName(name);
                    listdata.setPoints(points);
                    list.add(listdata);

                }

           try {
                Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Model>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Model lhs, Model rhs) {
                        int left = Integer.parseInt(rhs.getPoints());
                        int right = Integer.parseInt(lhs.getPoints());
                        return left - right;
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception ignored){}

                Adapter recyclerview = new Adapter(list, getActivity());
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
                recycler.setItemAnimator( new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recycler.setAdapter(recyclerview);

            }
```

This is the code I'm using for retrieving data from firebase.

and below is the data.

[image]

> I want to sort the data in ascending order but by the points. Maximum
>   the point will be on first.

I've already posted a question about it and it did the trick, the list is sorted but after some items it becomes unsorted.

AND THE POST IMPORTANT THING IS THE LIST IS VERY VERY BIG.

I'll show you an example:

[image]

AFTER SORTED, AND SOME ITEMS LATER IT BECOMES UNSORTED.

[image]

Can Anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Model>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Model lhs, Model rhs) {
                    int left = Integer.parseInt(rhs.getPoints());
                    int right = Integer.parseInt(lhs.getPoints());
                    return left - right;
                }
            });
```

**Replace to this**

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Model>() {
                @Override
      public int compare(Model o1, Model o2) {
               return Integer.compare(o2.getPoints(), o1.getPoints());
   }
});
```

**Update:**

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Model>() {
                    @Override
          public int compare(Model o1, Model o2) {
                   return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(o2.getPoints()), Integer.parseInt(o1.getPoints()));
       }
    });
```

**Please set exception see the below code : set break point and check any exception are fire or not**

```
try {
      Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Model>() {
          @Override
              public int compare(Model o1, Model o2) {
                       return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(o2.getPoints()), Integer.parseInt(o1.getPoints()));
           }
        });
   } catch (Exception ignored){
        ignored.getStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: i think your point var is string please see my updated answer

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: this code are given exception or not check my updated answer

Comment: Nothing changed.